# Apche JENA's integration with data virtualization tools

Tags: jboss, data-virtualization, teiid, apache-jena, r2rml

Anybody did any implementation of Apache JENA on top of RDF models(using R2RML mapping) created from Virtual Databases in Data Virtualization layer. I am specifically looking for integration with JBOSS-Teiid, Apache JENA, R2RML mapping.

Any reference or idea sharing would be a great help.